# How to add a function referencing another column to libreoffice-calc?

Tags: function, spreadsheet, libreoffice

Sorry for the simple question, I was expecting this to be a 2 minute job but it has proved much trickier to figure out than I planned, and the 'Function Wizard' has been no help.

I have a spreadsheet of products (one row = one product, columns = product name | stock | RRP etc).

Column D gives cost price excluding vat, I need to add another column giving cost including vat ( column D + 20% ).

I've figured out how to add functions to, and reference specific cels, so I can do it on a cel by cel basis =SUM(D2*(1.2))  but for obvious reasons, I'd rather do this once for the column instead of doing 10k+ products one by one! What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Fill Down" feature may be useful in your case:

- Select the first cell holding your formula and all the cells down your sheet where the formula should get inserted;
- Select Menu "`Edit`" -> "`Fill`" -> "`Down`", or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

This will make Calc to copy the formula into all selected cells, updating the cell references (except if you have absolute references using the dollar sign).

For 10k+ rows, this may take a short time, since Calc will calculate the results, too, but it should work at least.

Comment: 'For 10k+ rows, this may take a short time'  It sure saved more time than it took, thanks problem solved. I figured I was probably a `CTRL` + `Something` away :)